# Trying to use polymorphism and ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I have to use Polymorphism and ArrayList in my assignment in java but i need help. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me. I can't acces my subclass methods from ArrayLis.

So I have a superclass

```
    public class Table{
    private int TotalAmount;
    //setters and getters
    }
```

And I have two subclasses

```
    public class TableFidelity extends Table{
    private int Points;
    //setters and getters
    }


    public class TableCompany extends Table{
    private int NumberOfTimesServed;
    //setters and getters
    }
```

I have to use both my subclasses in the same ArrayList

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Table table=new Table();
    ArrayList<Table> Tables=new ArrayList<Table>();
    Table tablefidelity =new TableFidelity ();
    Table tablecompany =new TableCompany ();
    Tables.add(tablefidelity);
    Tables.add(tablecompany);
    System.out.println(Tables.get(0).getTotalAmount());
    //I can get the total Amount from the superclass
    System.out.println(Tables.get(0).getPoints());
    //but I can't do this
    System.out.println(Tables.get(1).NumberOfTimesServed());
    //or this 
    }
```

Netbeans dosen't show getPoints or NumberOfTimesServed when I press . it shows only the superclass methods.

Comment: That's because your compiler only knows that the list contains instances of `Table`; it can't know that there might be specific subclasses there, or that any particular element will be an element of a particular subclass.

Comment: That's because the compiler only knows that the elements in the list are of type `Table`. It doesn't know that element 0 is a `TableFidelity` etc. (and it shouldn't know that).

Comment: @AndyTurner ^^ gz on the almost identical first sentence ;)

Comment: To use methods only defined in the subclass, you have to cast the object to the subclass type : `((TableFidelity)(Tables.get(0)).getPoints())`

Comment: @Berger But the casted object will it have the same data as the previous object?

Comment: Sure. You can define a separate `List<TableFidelity>` and `List<TableCompany>`.

Comment: @Andy I have to use the same List  unfortunately

Comment: In that case, you haven't given us enough information to help you. The assignment asks for you to use polymorphism, but that's not going to be possible as things stand if you need to get access to fields that exist only in some of the subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is for each of your `Table`s to print information about what it contains, you'd be better off defining a method on the `Table` class to do that. You can then override this in your subclasses to print the extra information produced by those classes.

At the simplest level, you'd have

```
class Table {
  ....
  public void printInfo() {
    System.out.println(totalAmount);
  }
}
```

and then

```
class TableFidelity extends Table {
  ....
  @Override
  public void printInfo() {
    super.printInfo();
    System.out.println(Points);
  }
}
```

and so on. This is polymorphism at work: the class that invokes `printInfo()` doesn't need to know whether it's invoking it on a `Table` or a `TableFidelity` or whatever. The method overriding deals with that.

In practice, you might not want to restrict it to going to standard output. So you could pass in something to tell it where you want the information to go.

Perhaps even better, you could just override `toString()` in `Table` and its subclasses, along the lines above (but constructing a `String` instead of printing it). But it depends on exactly how you're going to use the classes.

One more note: if this is an assignment, you're probably going to drop marks for bad style for your naming conventions. Make sure your instance fields have names that start with lower case letters, not upper case.

Comment: @chiastic-security I have to use those variables in my assignment not only to print them. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: @Alb What do you have to use them for?

Comment: I have to make calculations of them in my main method. I tried to cast like this
      ((TableFidelity)(Tables.get(0)).getPoints()) 
but its not working

Comment: @Alb I suspect (but there isn't enough info here to be certain) that the calculations need to be pushed down to the classes, into a method that can be overridden. Otherwise there's no polymorphism anywhere. What calculations do you need to perform?

Comment: So i can't do a list with mixed subclasses?

Comment: I have to do a java project for a bar, and in each table I must choose what type of customer is

Comment: You can do a list with mixed subclasses, but the generic type of the list needs to be the common superclass (`Table` in this case). That part is correct. But if you want to do this with polymorphism, then whatever calculations you need to perform to work out the type of customer will need to be done in an overridden method, so that your `main()` method doesn't need to know about the subclasses. Do your calculations in the classes themselves, not in `main()`.